# How to install eslint for a javascript project?

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

I'm trying to install eslint for a javascript project.  But when I run the command: `npm install --save-dev eslint`

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@humanwhocodes%2fconfig-array - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@humanwhocodes/config-array@^0.5.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'eslint'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-07T17_32_17_971Z-debug.log
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There's currently an outage, check status updates: https://status.npmjs.org/